# Maven clean install failed to execute goal maven failsafe plugin with openjdk 11

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-failsafe-plugin, openjdk-11

I am facing issue with maven clean install of project using openjdk 11, which was build successfully by using jdk 8. Showing failed to execute goal maven failsafe plugin, and error occurred in starting fork.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:3.0.0-M3:verify (default) on project service: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /Users/albin/workspace/service/target/failsafe-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was /bin/sh -c cd /Users/albin/workspace/service/ && /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java '-javaagent:/users/albin/libs/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.9/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.9-runtime.jar=destfile=/Users/albin/workspace/service/target/jacoco.exec,excludes=**com.steadystate*' -jar /Users/albin/workspace/service/target/surefire/surefirebooter724926991048705750.jar /Users/albin/workspace/service/target/surefire 2019-07-17T11-40-23_910-jvmRun1 surefire11075145238958756154tmp surefire_010847657721829744077tmp
[ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 134
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:670)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:283)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:246)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1161)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1002)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:848)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:192)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

plugin details as follows

```
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>verify</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>11</source>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

and using jacoco plugin with version 0.7.9 as java agent for creating code coverage reports

Answer (score 0):

## Specify the provider manually

We are migrating to Open JDK11 a series of legacy projects. We faced a failsafe failure just by changing the JDK, without changes in the project POM or otherwise. Moving from 1.8.0_121 to 11 raised failsafe failure with "NullPointerException":

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:2.20.1:integration-test
(default-cli) on project lib-mit8movimientosentretiendas-impl-local: Execution default-cli
of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:2.20.1:integration-test failed.:
NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
```

Looking around we didn't see any indication pointing to a solution. We saw some comments about using newer versions (and not even the 3.0.0-M3, whose reports are compatible with JDK11, but as old a 2.22.0), or moving the plugin declaration from section `pluginManagement` to `plugins`... but neither helped.

Then we noticed that our declaration was specifying the provider manually with version 2.12 for JUnit 4.7.

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.15</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                        <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                        <version>2.12</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

But not for the module that was now failing. We added the manual specification of the provider and it stopped failing.

It looks like there is something messing up with the versions and failsafe would resolve the wrong provider if not indicated.

See "Manually Specifying a Provider" section at the ["Using JUnit" documentation page](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/junit.html) for failsafe plugin.